# Visualforce inside standar page layout

Tags: apex, visualforce

I don't want to change my account standar layout to visualforce but I need to add a little visualforce inside this page with a form.

Is there any possibility (editing page) when the user click the standar save button to save de data in account and in the visualforce?.

What is the best approach? Two Buttons? One is the standar save button in account and other save button inside the visualforce?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control the Save action and this asks for huge customization .If you need something to be automated ,I would suggest to go with the Trigger in backend but if you need input from User provide one more button on the layout for the action .